# I agree - on multiple forms - coponent

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a requirement to produce a consent box inside a lot of forms in an application.

I used jQuery to build a component that disabled the submit button until the consent checkbox was checked. This doesn't cut it as the product owner wants to return an error message if the checkbox isn't checked i.e. part of the ModelState errors.

What is the best way to go about this without having to alter all the ViewModels associated with the forms, and keep a nice generic partial that could be used on any page (the only thing that changes is the I agree - consent text

Comment: `<form onsubmit="return confirm('Do you agree?')">` ?

Comment: Nice but it has to be a disclaimer type message with a checkbox that they opt into.

If they don;t click the checkbox an error needs to me added to the ModelState - ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please agree to our terms before proceeding");

Comment: You can trade `confirm()` for anything that returns `true/false`.

Comment: Thanks Havenard, like I said it needs to be a checkbox at the bottom of the page, the customer is very picky about the UI and this is the way they want it to work. DO you know how to achieve what I asked in the original question without a JS popup?

Comment: Ok. Then make a function to verify the checkbox state and if its not checked you highlight it or something.

Comment: Yea that is what I am hoping to get an answer for, best practice/way of doing that without altering a lot of view models/controller methods.

Answer (score 6):

What I can read from your description, as well as the comments from others, you want as little work as possible and need to apply the requested behaviour a lot of times. And you don't want to edit your models.

Especially considering the latter, the most logic option is going for a clientside solution for which I've provided a possible solution below. However, I'm also giving a second option that requires a bit more work but will give you more flexibility on the ModelState side of your code.

> Note: Both options below aren't 100% reusable samples. It still requires some work on your side, based on how your forms are setup.

**Option 1: clientside script**
The first option is to simply hook up to the form post event and do your magic there. Something like:

```
<script>
    // Hook into the form submit event
    // In this case, fetch the first form we encounter
    $("form:first-of-type").submit(function (e) {

        // fetch the *last* checkbox in the appropriate form
        // assuming the last checkbox is always the 'agree' checkbox
        var agreedCheckBox = $("input[type='checkbox']:last-of-type");

        if (!agreedCheckBox.is(':checked')) {
            // nope, it's not checked so do your magic here
            // TODO: Show alert... do something

            // Also, don't forget to cancel the form post
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
</script>
```

Now what will this do:

1. It hooks onto the form submit event
2. It checks if the **last checkbox** on that form is 'checked'
3. If it is not checked, it prevents the form submit and you can do whatever you want in there

This is ideal in the situation where you don't want to edit the code, change the models etc. And the big bonus is that it can easily be refactored in a reusable snippet which can be included on the fly.

**Option 2: Custom ModelBinder**
The second option is also a quickwin but has a focus on your server-side code: you could create a custom model binder that'll check for the appropriate checkbox (last?) to be checked. If not, you can easily add a ModelStateError there. Like so:

```
public class RequireConsentModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        // TODO: Iterate through the 'request.Form' values, find the last checkbox
        // and see if it's checked
        if (!checked)
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("", "You forgot to agree to our terms, silly you...");

        return bindingContext.Model;
    }
}
```

This option is a bit more obtrusive in your code than the simple Javascript solution from option 1, considering you need to manually tell MVC on what Actions this binder should do its work:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomePost([ModelBinder(typeof(RequireConsentModelBinder))]FormCollection form)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // here is where you'll know if it worked...
        }

        return View();
    }
```

With this approach you also has the advantage that you don't have to edit any of your models; it's only required to change the signature of your ActionResult's parameters in order for this to comply. Last bonus is you can inject the ModelState at will.

Hope this helped...

Answer (score 1):

I would just have it evaluate whether the checkbox is marked when you click the button, or else through an alert to the user. 
Here's also an example if needed http://plnkr.co/edit/Z0Hts5qzUl3eBa8LaDpD?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    if ($('#agreeCheck').is(':checked')) {
      alert('Checkbox is checked!')


      /*Code here for if box is checked*/


    } else {
      alert('Must agree to terms and conditions!');
    }
  });
});
```